# How do I write Json data in multiple json files, using java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

with the below code, I am able to write list of users into single json file,But I want to separate files Based on size, i.e, when one of the json file size is 20kb, i want to create a new json file and write on that file. How this can be done? I am using json-simple for this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public void getAllUsers() {
        List<User> userList=userRepository.findAll();
        if(!userList.isEmpty()) {
            JSONArrray userArray=new JSONArrray();
            JSONObject userObject=new JSONObject();
            for(User user:userList) {
                userObject.put("id", user.getId());
                userObject.put("name", user.getName());
                userObject.put("email", user.getEmail());
                userObject.put("password", user.getPassword());
                userArray.add(userObject);
            }
            
           try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/Users/nabinsingh34/Desktop/project/SpringBoot/user-management/src/main/resources/user-1.json")) {
                file.write(userArray.toJSONString());
                file.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No users found");
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which specific library called "JSON Simple" are you using? And what version?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot which provides Jackson out-of-the-box. I am wondering why you chose JSON Simple.  The advantage of using Jackson is it provides support for [streaming JSON objects](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api), so you can count how many objects you have processed and decide a threshold for when you want to write a chunk of them to a new file. I don't know if the JSON Simple library you are using (whichever one that is) can do that.

Comment: Another thought: You could keep it very simple and use what you already have, but add some batch logic around the serializer, using a traditional `for` loop instead of your enhanced `for` loop: `for(int i = start; i < end; i++)` - and logic to update `start` and `end` for the subset of each batch of `users.get(i)` objects. Whatever you do, you would have to estimate the file size to figure out a suitable batch number.